# For Loops and stopping conditions

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Can anyone explain why the answers are what they are please? The first one i guess its because the stopping condition is already reached so it skips the statement but question 13 why would it not print 4321?

**12.What output is produced by the following code:**

```
int n;
for (n = 1; n > 4; n++)
    System.out.print(n);
```

a)   12345

b)   1234

c)   0 ---> for loop never runs because stopping condition already met.

d)   It produces no output*

**13.What output is produced by the following code:**

```
int n;
for (n = 4; n > 0; n--);  
    System.out.print(n);
```

a)   43210

b)   4321

c)   0*  ---> semi colon after for loop, causing print statement to run after loop is finished

d)   It produces no output

Comment: You should better have listen to your teacher instead of playing Angry Birds on your iPhone :)

Comment: If this is homework, it should be tagged as such ;)

Comment: A lot of teachers/professors reuse questions from quizzes and exams.  Are you sure that your teacher doesn't mind you posting the questions and answers online?

Comment: @sp00m, thanks ill keep it in mind.

Comment: @FrankPaaske, its not homeowrk, it was a quiz im reviewing

Comment: @AdamMihalcin, im not sure, she never mentioned it.

Comment: @Batman To mark a question as answered, don't append (Answered) to the question title.  Just click the check mark beside the best posted answer.  StackOverflow will mark the question answered for other people to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding question 13: there's a semicolon behind the for-loop. Because of that, the loop will first be execuetd until n no longer is > 0 => it is zero then. Then, the print will show a zero.

Comment: Wow, been staring at this question for a good 10minutes and never noticed that. Thanks.

Comment: @Batman you set it to answered by clicking the checkmark next to the answer that suits you.  (not by changing the title :))

Answer (score 0):

The first will produce no output as the for loop body is never run (assuming that the print line is within the for loop).
The second appears to do nothing in the for loop and just prints the value of n after the loop. Which would be 0 as it has just failed a test for being greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

In **Question 13** :

`for (n = 4; n > 0; n--);`

the loop executes directly. So, It just decreases the value of n, and didnot enter to the next statement until it completes its execution. So, here it won't come to statement **until** it completes its execution. **At the End** of execution value of n is 0. So, when it comes to statement

`System.out.print(n);`

value of **n is 0** , so the output of the program is 0

Answer (score 0):

In question 13) there's a ; after the for-loop, it means that the program do nothing but (n--) 4 times. It results that the value of n become 0.